# Insert cells when condition met

Tags: excel, vba

My Excel sheet has 6 columns as follows:
Column A: New Row,
Column B: New Dup,
Column C: New Fabric,
Column D: Location,
Column E: True Sort,
Column F: Excel Sort,

I would like to know how to write a macro that searches column B and in every occurrence of the word "Right" in column B, a blank space is inserted in the corresponding row in columns D, E, and F, then the results from the corresponding columns in the row above are duplicated into those cells.

ie:  First occurrence of the word "Right" is in B187.  The macro will insert a blank cell in D187, E187, and F187, then will copy the data in D186 into D187, the data from E186 into E187, and the data from F186 into F 187.

The file has 750 rows.
Thanks for any insight!
Carl

Comment: You can use the Find method, and then record a macro for the rest, or Google it - there's lots of material out there. Come back once you've tried some code and got stuck - people here are generally not inclined to write code from scratch.

Comment: With all the inserting of cells in the rows, wont you be offshifting a lot of your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you would want to add a space into the cells and then copy the details from the row above, so the code below simply copies the values from the row above:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column B
For i = 1 To LastRow 'loop from first row to last
    If UCase(ws.Cells(i, 2)) = "RIGHT" Then 'check if the word "Right" is in cell regardless of it being uppercase or lowercase
        ws.Range("D" & i & ":F" & i).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        ws.Cells(i, 3) = ws.Cells(i - 1, 3) 'get values from row above
        ws.Cells(i, 4) = ws.Cells(i - 1, 4)
        ws.Cells(i, 5) = ws.Cells(i - 1, 5)
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: He might also need cells inserted at those locations as well (just going off his post)

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this at work tomorrow
Left columns are fabrics hung on rods. A few of the samples share 1 rod.  Right columns are rod locations.  Left columns are longer than right due to doubled fabrics.  Inserting rows equalizes the left and right columns.
ie: Left column lists fabrics 1, 2, and 3. Right column lists locations 1, 2, and 3.  Fabrics 1 and  2 share a location.  I need for the right columns to reflect locations 1, 1A, and 2.  Shifting the cells in the right columns down and adding the data will equalize the columns and allow me to sort the file by location or by fabric.

Comment: I don't understand how many cells you are trying to insert, and when you insert a cell you want the other cells to move to the right? I've updated my answer to show you how to insert a cell, you will need to amend this to add as many cells as you require...

Comment: Thank you SO much!  I made a few slight modifications and it is perfect.

Comment: @Carl, please could you accept my response as an answer if it has helped you? Thanks :)